# SpringBoot ResourceBundleMessageSource with external remote files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I'm trying to setup the MessageSource for the internalization of my Spring Boot App using external files.

Basically, my idea is to have the localized files out of the box (for example on AWS S3 or something like this).

I'm trying using this code:

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    rs.setBasename("http://www.myexternalservice.com/messages");
    rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return rs;
}
```

When I try to retrieve a message I use this:

String message = messageSource.getMessage("keyname", null, Locale.US);

But, in this case I read into the debug console this:

```
ResourceBundle [http://www.myexternalservice.com/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name http://www.myexternalservice.com/messages, locale en_US
```

I tried also with different Locale.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this code example:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("http://www.myexternalservice.com/messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(400);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
}
```